# Elastic search string filter - does such option exists?

Tags: elasticsearch, error-handling, query-string

I am wondering, is there such an option like string filter?

I've recently bumped into the following error:

> RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception',
>   'too_many_clauses: maxClauseCount is set to 1024')

According to Lucene's documentation, it says:

Use a filter to replace the part of the query that causes the exception.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: It is not clear to me what is what you are doing. Please post relevant mappings and queries.

Comment: Found a solution via 'request_timeout = 30'.

Answer (score 0):

The Lucene FAQ mentions a few approaches to overcoming the TooManyClauses exception which  doesn't apply to Elasticsearch as before they used to have [terms filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/query-dsl-terms-filter.html)  separately but now its part of terms query itself.

so below is the example how you could use terms in the filter context:

```
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 

      "filter": [ 
        { "term":   { "user" : ["kimchy", "elasticsearch"]}, 

      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you really need to use a query instead of a filter then you can update 
`indices.query.bool.max_clause_count: n` in the elasticsearch.yml (replace n with the number of clause count that you need) file of each node of the cluster and restart the cluster.

> Note that this will increase the
>   memory requirements for searches that expand to many terms.

Comment: I am not allowed to do changes on .yml as it would affect the production results. Sorry and thanks!